# Can't find dynamically created TD in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a dynamic table in my code behind which loads up on page load. I have created a button which when clicked I need to add a `<div>` to specific `<td>` in the table. However, it is not finding my `<td>` element using the id. What am I doing wrong?

```
Function CalendarRefresh(Day As Integer, MonthDays As Integer)

    Dim iDay As Integer = 1
    Dim TableID As Integer
    Dim TDCount As Integer = 0
    Dim FullTDCount As Integer = 0 '42
    Dim StringHtml As New StringBuilder
    Dim DaysInMonth As Integer = MonthDays
    clsWork.GetUnscheduledWork()
    Dim ClientName = "Terence Creighton" ' Test Replace with DB Value
    Dim JobName = "Install Job"

    ' Top structure of table
    StringHtml.Append("<table id='calendar' runatserver='server'>")
    StringHtml.Append("<tr class='weekdays'>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Sunday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Monday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Tuesday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Wednesday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Thursday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Friday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("<th scope='col'>Saturday</th>")
    StringHtml.Append("</tr>")


    StringHtml.Append("<tr Class='days'>")
    If Day > 1 Then

        Do While iDay < (Day)
            ' add Previous month style
            StringHtml.Append("<td  class='day other-month'>")
            StringHtml.Append("</td>")

            iDay = iDay + 1
            TDCount = TDCount + 1
            FullTDCount = FullTDCount + 1
        Loop

    End If

    For i As Integer = 1 To DaysInMonth

        If TDCount = 7 Then
            StringHtml.Append("</tr>")
            StringHtml.Append("<tr class='days'>")
            TDCount = 0
            FullTDCount = FullTDCount + 1
            i = i - 1
        Else
            StringHtml.Append("<td class='day' ")
            StringHtml.Append("id='")
            StringHtml.Append(i)
            StringHtml.Append("' Runat='server'>")
            StringHtml.Append("<div class='date'>")
            StringHtml.Append(i)
            StringHtml.Append("</div>")

            'StringHtml.Append("<div id='")
            'StringHtml.Append(i)
            'StringHtml.Append("' Runat='server'>")
            'StringHtml.Append("<div Class='panel panel-primary' draggable='true'>")
            'StringHtml.Append("<div Class='panel-heading'>")
            'StringHtml.Append(ClientName)
            'StringHtml.Append("</div>")
            'StringHtml.Append("<div Class='panel-body'>")
            'StringHtml.Append(JobName)
            'StringHtml.Append("</div>")
            'StringHtml.Append("</div>")

            StringHtml.Append("</div>")
            StringHtml.Append("</td>")
            TDCount = TDCount + 1
            FullTDCount = FullTDCount + 1
        End If

    Next

    StringHtml.Append("</tr>")
    StringHtml.Append("</table>")

    Return StringHtml.ToString

End Function

Public Sub ScheduledJobs()

    Dim StringHtml As New StringBuilder
    Dim ClientName As String
    Dim JobName As String
    Dim Work = clsWork.GetUnscheduledWork()


    For Each i As Integer In Work.Rows.Count
        ClientName = Work.Rows(i).Items("ClientName").ToString
        JobName = Work.Rows(i).Items("JobName").ToString
        ID = i.ToString
        StringHtml.Append("<div class='panel panel-primary' draggable='true' ondragstart='OnDragStart' ondrop='OnDrop' ")
        StringHtml.Append("id='")
        StringHtml.Append(ID)
        StringHtml.Append("'>")

        StringHtml.Append("<div class='panel-heading'>")
        StringHtml.Append(ClientName)
        StringHtml.Append("</div>")
        StringHtml.Append("<div class='panel-body'>")
        StringHtml.Append(JobName)
        StringHtml.Append("</div>")
    Next

    Dim MyTable As HtmlTable = Page.FindControl("calendar")
    Dim MyCell As HtmlTableCell
    MyCell.ID = "19"

    If MyCell Is Nothing Then
        messageResponse = "Tablecell not found"
    Else
        MyCell.InnerHtml = StringHtml.ToString

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdLoadJobs_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdTry.ServerClick
    ScheduledJobs()
End Sub
```

I am expecting find the td with the ID and add the html string in the ("td Element").innerhtml. I have tried various combinations of findcontrol but all turns up empty

Comment: This approach won't work.  ASP.NET needs you to use real controls and you are just sending HTML string data.  I am not sure where to start explaining.  Try using the System.UI.Web.Controls.WeControls.  There is a Table control.

Comment: Would I be able to find the td element using something like the "Findcontrol" function I have tried searching for the td using the ID when I create the table in html code and not doing it dynamically

Comment: No.  And its a lot to explain in the comments.  But in short ... your page has a duel life.  It lives on the server and on the web browser .. and these two things are disconnected even through ASP.NET tried to make it feel otherwise.  Microsoft Web controls because they have both a server and client side component and so when your page posts back, the control data is included in the Form and ASP.NET maps that data back into the control on the server.  So the asp:textfield id=foo inherits the value from the textfield id=foo on the page.  Watch some Youtube videos to learn more.

Comment: Thanks that makes it clearer. Will use an actual control versus dynamic html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create real dynamic controls. Here a very basic example of how to interact with a dynamically created table.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //do not create dynamic control in an ispostback check
    }

    //create some table and it's rows and cells. note the assignent of an ID
    Table table = new Table()
    {
        ID = "MyTable1"
    };
    TableRow row = new TableRow()
    {
        ID = "MyRow1"
    };
    TableCell cell = new TableCell()
    {
        ID = "MyCell1",
        Text = "My 1st cell"
    };

    //add the cell to the row
    row.Controls.Add(cell);

    //add the row to the table
    table.Controls.Add(row);

    //add the table to the page
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);
}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //use findcontrol to locate the cell
    TableCell cell = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("MyCell1") as TableCell;

    //interact with it
    cell.Text = "Cell Found!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this:

```
StringHtml.Append("<table id='calendar' runatserver='server'>")
```

While it's certainly fine to push raw html to a page in the browser by building an html string, *you cannot create server controls this way.* You won't be able to access anything in that html from your code behind. The `runat='server'` part is first of all keyed wrong, but would be worthless even if written correctly. By the time you're in the Page_Load event, everything that looks for the `runat='server'` attribute has **already finished**.